# Vaciar campo date al hacer click con Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, angular7

tengo un input tipo date que me gustaría vaciarlo al hacer click en otra parte de mi página web. Igualándolo a null no se me vacía a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" [(ngModel)]='auxHistorialFechaCre' aria-describedby="date" [disabled]="!modify">
</div>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas  y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden.

Answer (score 3):

JQUERY:

```
$("#date").val(null);
```

Si quieres realizarlo en el click de un elemento podrías hacer algo como:

```js
$("body").click(function(){
  if($("#date").val() != "" && $("#date").val() != null ){
    console.log("Valor antes de borrar: "+$("#date").val());
    $("#date").val(null);
    console.log("Valor despues de borrar: "+$("#date").val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" [(ngModel)]='auxHistorialFechaCre' aria-describedby="date" [disabled]="!modify" value="12/07/2005">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin más información es difícil saber donde puede estar el problema. Pero si poner  nulo no lo "vacía" es porque no se está poniendo a nulo el valor correcto:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" [(ngModel)]="auxHistorialFechaCre" aria-describedby="date" disabled="!modified">
</div>
<button (click)="auxHistorialFechaCre = null">VACIAR</button>
```

Aqui un enlace un stackblitz donde se ve como funciona ok

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-45bpic